# Representation of Array program in java

Tags: java

I want to know the array representaion of this code,

```
int []x[]={{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8,9}};
```

The program is:

```
 class Testsss 
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int []x[]={{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8,9}};
       int [][]y=x;
       System.out.println(y[2][1]);
    }
  }
```

Output is 7, as I executed. How can the values are represented in array form.

Comment: Please ask a clear question.

Comment: Array start from 0 not from 1, but I am not sure that is the answer for your question...

Comment: The question is how the values given in x variable is represented in an array form.

Comment: int[2][2] x is represnted as 00 01 10 11 [Matrix form].                                As given the values in x varaible in program, the values are not clear, so as to represent in array form

Comment: Maybe you want this System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(y)); Not sure I understand the actual question

Comment: Well, arrays are, if you want so, some type of matrix, but are not necesserly represantable as a matrix (especially if the arrays are of different size). A two dimensional array is basicly just an array of arrays. In this case, the first array would be of the size 2, the second of the size 3, the fourth of the size 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []x[]={{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8,9}};
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("x["+i+"]["+j+"]= " + x[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
x[0][0]= 1
x[0][1]= 2
x[1][0]= 3
x[1][1]= 4
x[1][2]= 5
x[2][0]= 6
x[2][1]= 7
x[2][2]= 8
x[2][3]= 9
```

Comment: Hey. Got it. Now am clear. Thanks a ton.